# Pusher notification with Laravel 5.4 not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, notifications, pusher

So I'm really stuck for a while now, with Laravel event and pusher API. 
I created event and broadcast, but when I access with pusher Javascript API it returns empty array, when I try to print it in the route it also returns empty array, meanwhile if I check Laravel log stoarage/logs/laravel.log I see exactly what I am expecting in the Javascript and route.
My code:

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=******
PUSHER_APP_KEY=524**************8
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=d2**************c
```

Boadcasting.php

```
'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),
    'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
    'cluster' => 'us2',
    'encrypted' => true
    ],
    ],
```

The event class: ProjectEvent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ProjectEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $username;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->message  = "{$username} sent you a message";
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['project-update'];
    }

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    print_r(event(new App\Events\ProjectEvent('Michel')));
    //return "Event has been sent!";
});

Route::get('/view', function () {
    return view('testevent');
});
```

testevent.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
    <body>

      <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://js.pusher.com/3.1/pusher.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

      Pusher.logToConsole = true;

      var pusher = new Pusher('524************8', {
        cluster: 'us2',
        encrypted: true
      });

      var channel = pusher.subscribe('project-update');

      channel.bind('App\\Events\\ProjectEvent', function(data) {
        alert(data.message);
      });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I really can't figure out where it all going wrong, since I am able to see the event in the log while the JS alert isn't working, also I try to dump the event on the route, it return empty `array()`

Comment: Could you show us your logs, too?

Comment: @jameshfisher I've passed that stage already. I was able to fix it. All working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: @Michel, what was the solution. I am stuck in the same issue.